# Amend list using linq via second list

Tags: c#, linq, missing-data

I have 2 lists. The first is the main list containing a bunch of objects, each having timestamp (Datetime), type (int), value (double) and flag (int). The second list has type (int) and description (string).

My problem is that I need the first list to have all types at each timestamp. In the case where there is no such object matching (timestamp,type), I need to insert a new object with (timestamp,type, null value and null flags).

How do I do that using Linq?

Example objects:

```
var date = DateTime.UtcNow;
var points = new List<Point> {
    new Point { ts_utc = date            , type = 300, value = 25     , flags = 0 },
    new Point { ts_utc = date            , type = 400, value = 250    , flags = 0 },
    new Point { ts_utc = date            , type = 500, value = 2500   , flags = 0 },
    new Point { ts_utc = date.AddDays(1) , type = 300, value = 26     , flags = 0 },
    //new Point { ts_utc = date.AddDays(1) , type = 400, value = 260, flags = 0 },
    new Point { ts_utc = date.AddDays(1) , type = 500, value = 2600   , flags = 0 },
    new Point { ts_utc = date.AddDays(2) , type = 300, value = 27     , flags = 0 },
    new Point { ts_utc = date.AddDays(2) , type = 400, value = 270    , flags = 0 },
    new Point { ts_utc = date.AddDays(2) , type = 500, value = 2700   , flags = 0 }
};
var desc = new List<Description> {
    new Description{ type = 300, description = "300" },
    new Description{ type = 400, description = "400" },
    new Description{ type = 500, description = "500" },
};

 var q = from p in points
         join d in desc on p.type equals d.type into joined
         from subd in joined.DefaultIfEmpty(...)
         ...
```

The query is incomplete. In the list above, I have commented one Point as an example of a missing value for that (timestamp,type) combination. In that spot, I'd like to have a default object inserted with the timestamp from an existing type, but with the missing type inserted. Value and flags should be null. I guess a group by might come in handy?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you want the set of time stamps and type combinations that do not exist in the first collection based on that collection having one entry for a time stamp, but not all the types in the second collection.

```
var missing = points.GroupBy(p => p.ts_utc)
                    .SelectMany(g => desc.Where(d => g.All(p => p.type != d.type))
                                          .Select(d => new 
                                                       { 
                                                           ts = g.Key, 
                                                           type = d.type 
                                                       }));
```

This will first group the points by the time stamp then for each grouping it will filter from the description list any descriptions that have a type that exists in the group, leaving only the descriptions with a type that doesn't exist for this time stamp.  Then it selects the time stamp from the group key and the "missing" type.  finally the `SelectMany` will flatten the results.

You can then iterate over the results and add entries into the `points` collection.

```
foreach(var m in missing)
    points.Add(new Point { ts_utc = m.ts, type = m.type });
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong but you want to 'fill in the gaps' for list 1 - such that it contains entries with every existing type for every existing date?

If so, I would just get all distinct items to iterate through and create a nested foreach loop...

```
List<DateTime> allExistingDates = points.Select(o => o.ts_utc).Distinct().ToList();
List<int> allExistingTypes = points.Select(o => o.type).Concat(desc.Select(o => o.type)).Distinct().ToList();

foreach (DateTime d in allExistingDates)
    foreach (int t in allExistingTypes)
        if (points.Any(o => o.ts_utc == d && o.type == t) == false)
            points.Add(new Point { ts_utc = d, type = t});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this to fix my list without having to resort to multiple queries:

```
var w = from p in points
        group p by p.ts_utc into g
        from d in desc
        select points.Where(r => r.ts_utc == g.Key && r.type == d.type).DefaultIfEmpty(new Point
        {
            ts_utc = g.Key,
            type = d.type
        }).FirstOrDefault();
```

I thinks it doesn't get any shorter than this. Both (at this time) other answers helped me to arrive at this solution. It doesn't create unnecessary new points, is 1 linq query, and I think (using 1 linq query) that it couldn't be much more efficient.

Comment: This also would "remove" duplicates based on the time stamp and type.

Comment: True. Fortunately, I can be very sure that duplicates will not occur.